# Flutter image_picker is not working with PlatformException like macos

Tags: flutter

I am currently in a crisis of cross platform i have an existing app for android and ios now. I wanted that in web and macOS now i am using image_picker in package now the problem is that image picker is not working for the macOS i have tried other packages to for the purpose so can you guys suggest me a package for the same or some way to access and get photos in macOS

Comment: Check supported platforms before adding the dependencies the package you mentioned is not supporting for MACOS https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Can you please suggest  me the way how can i choose image from macOS

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_instagram_image_picker

Comment: @DineshNagarajan For this i have to integrate with instagram compulsory ? or else using for that method only ?